# sending file through webscoket in browser with js to c# server

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, websocket, file-transfer

I have a problem in sending file through webscoket in browser with js to c# server.
When I want to save the buffer, if it is a txt file, there is no problem
But if it is a photo, for example, the photo will not be opened after saving
Where am I going wrong?

```
private void BeginReceive()
{
    try
    {
        Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        Socket.BeginReceive(Buffer, 0, BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), this);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "BeginReceive", ex.Message);
        Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "BeginReceive", ex.Message);
    }
}

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        if (CheckState(ar))
        {
            int bytesRead = Socket.EndReceive(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "bytesRead: ", bytesRead);
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\01.jpg", Helper.DecodedBytes(Buffer, bytesRead));
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "ReceiveCallback", ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(!Helper.SocketIsDisposed(Socket))  BeginReceive();
    }
}
```

I think the problem is with the decode function

```
 public static string DecodedBytes(byte[] buffer, int length)
 {
    if(buffer[0] == 136 && (buffer[1] == 130 || buffer[1] == 128)) throw new System.Net.Sockets.SocketException(10054); //[10054]: Connection reset by peer
    byte b = buffer[1];
    int dataLength = 0;
    int totalLength = 0;
    int keyIndex = 0;

    if (b - 128 <= 125)
    {
        dataLength = b - 128;
        keyIndex = 2;
        totalLength = dataLength + 6;
    }

    if (b - 128 == 126)
    {
        dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { buffer[3], buffer[2] }, 0);
        keyIndex = 4;
        totalLength = dataLength + 8;
    }

    if (b - 128 == 127)
    {
        dataLength = (int)BitConverter.ToInt64(new byte[] { buffer[9], buffer[8], buffer[7], buffer[6], buffer[5], buffer[4], buffer[3], buffer[2] }, 0);
        keyIndex = 10;
        totalLength = dataLength + 14;
    }

    if (totalLength > length)
        throw new Exception("The buffer length is small than the data length");

    byte[] key = new byte[] { buffer[keyIndex], buffer[keyIndex + 1], buffer[keyIndex + 2], buffer[keyIndex + 3] };

    int dataIndex = keyIndex + 4;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = dataIndex; i < totalLength; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] ^ key[count % 4]);
        count++;
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, dataIndex, dataLength);
}
```

and js code:

```
connect:function(){
        var root = this;
        root.websocket = new WebSocket(root.url);
        root.websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
        root.websocket.onopen = () => root.fireEvent('connect');
        root.websocket.onmessage = (e) => {
            root.fireEvent('receive',JSON.parse(e.data));
        }
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
            root.websocket.onclose = function () {}; 
            root.websocket.close();
        });
    },
sendFile:function(){
        var root = this;
        var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
        var loader = new FileReader();
        loader.onload = (e) => {
            var a = e.target.result;
            root.controller.websocket.send(e.target.result);
        }
        loader.readAsText(file)
    },
```

Comment: Test the encode and decode methods to see if the work properly.  Put the encode and decode into a method.  Take image and endcode than decode the results and make sure the input and output exactly match.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

JS code changed to:

```
sendFile:function(){
    var root = this;
    var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
    var loader = new FileReader();
    loader.onload = (e) => {
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        root.controller.websocket.send(byteArray.buffer);
    }
    loader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

and C# code changed to:
WriteAllText to WriteAllBytes

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\01.jpg", Helper.DecodedBytes(Buffer, bytesRead));
```

and Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, dataIndex, dataLength) to buffer.Skip(dataIndex).ToArray()

```
return buffer.Skip(dataIndex).ToArray();
```